# what's the error in this for loop >> java netbeans

Tags: java, for-loop

This is a method that displays the contents of the product in the table I did.

```
public void Show_Products_In_Jatable(){
    
    ArrayList<product> list = getProductList();
    DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) TTT.getModel();
    
    Object[] row = new Object[4];
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size() ; i++){
        
        row[0] = list.get(i).getId();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getName();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getPrice();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getAddDate();

        model.addRow(row);               
    }
}
```

But when I add or delete other products, it will automatically recur, as in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTYh8.png).

Maybe the problem is here

```
public ArrayList<product> getProductList() {

    ArrayList<product> productList = new ArrayList<product>();
    Connection con = getConnection();
    String query = "select * from products";

    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        product product;
        
        while(rs.next()){
            product = new product(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), Float.parseFloat(rs.getString("price")), rs.getString("add_date"), rs.getBytes("image"));
            productList.add(product);
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return productList;
}
```

Comment: You're adding a reference to the same array for every iteration. Move `Object[] row = new Object[4];` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the row declaration

```
Object[] row = new Object[4];
```

inside the for loop, otherwise you're creating just one single object which gets modified each time you cycle through the loop and eventually your "model" object will contain multiple references of the same object all over.

The whole row declaration and for loop would look a lot nicer if you replace it with lambdas though:

```
list.stream().forEach(i -> {
  model.addRow(new Object[] {
    i.getId(),
    i.getName(),
    i.getPrice(),
    i.getAddDate()
  });
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: I tried it but, it didn't work, 

you mean this 

        for (int i = 0; i<list.size() ; i++){
            
            Object[] row = new Object[4];

Comment: it didn't work too, but its better than for loop 

please read my last answer

Comment: In your question you've mentioned a picture ("it will automatically recur, as in the picture") but there isn't any.
Sorry to say but as long as we don't know what result you expect and what result you actually get, I'm afraid we're stuck with guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Show_Products_In_Jatable(){
    
    ArrayList<product> list = getProductList();
    DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) TTT.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size() ; i++){
       Object[] row = new Object[4];  
       row[0] = list.get(i).getId();
       row[1] = list.get(i).getName();
       row[2] = list.get(i).getPrice();
       row[3] = list.get(i).getAddDate(); 
       model.addRow(row);             
    }
}
```

Comment: it'll be helpful to the OP if you can explain what you changed and why that was necessary.